# The recovery model cannot be changed to SIMPLE when any files are subject to a RESTORE PAGE operation

Tags: sql-server, restore

One of my pages in database needed restore. so I did a restoration by this command:

```
USE master RESTORE DATABASE myDB PAGE = '1:4171728'FROM DISK = 'D:\Backups\Database\myDB.bak 'WITH NORECOVERY"
```

The problem with that page was solved. But another problem occurred. I cannot do a backup or change a recovery model. The error is: "Backup of file 'myDB' is not permitted because it contains pages subject to an online restore sequence. Complete the restore sequence before taking the backup, or restrict the backup to exclude this file."

What should I do?

I tried DBCC CheckDB and no errors. Database works fine. But unable to perform a backup nor changing a recovery model.

Comment: Your `RESTORE` statement shows it was done [WITH NORECOVERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#norecovery). Did you run a separate `RESTORE...WITH RECOVERY`?

Comment: Yes, it was with norecovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution! I couldn't take full backup from the database, so I started taking log backup and then I detached the database and restore the database again from the full backup I had and those log backups. The problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, after restoring a page from a full backup, you have to apply all log backups and the tail log backup at the end:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [<database>] PAGE='1:xx'  
   FROM DISK = '<file_backup>'
   WITH NORECOVERY;
RESTORE LOG [<database>] FROM [<log_backup>]
   WITH NORECOVERY;
RESTORE LOG [<database>] FROM [<log_backup>]
   WITH NORECOVERY;
(...)
BACKUP LOG [<database>] TO [<new_log_backup>];
RESTORE LOG [<database>] FROM [<new_log_backup>] WITH RECOVERY;
GO
```

After you have finished the sequence you simply have to recover from the restore operations.

```
RESTORE DATABASE myDB WITH RECOVERY;
```

Comment: I didnt have any log backup. only a full backup before restoring the page.

Comment: Page restore applies only to SQL Server databases that are using the full or bulk-logged recovery models.
If you set the database in full recovery model for restoring this page after you have found the broken page, you have a problem. You don't have the proper log backups and you can't recover from this situation.